# Java - Difficulty with using Pair for Map Key in EULER Coins

Tags: java, reference, maps, key

I've been working on a Project Euler problem about coin combinations. I got the answer using recursion, but I wanted to try some dynamic programming so I built myself a Pair class and tried to use it as a key for a TreeMap. I was able to get it going but I kept getting the completely wrong solution.

I'm not sure what is going on. My friend suggested that perhaps something was happening with the Map trying to match the Pair references rather than values, but I tried overriding the .equals and modifying the compareTo method and it still doesn't work. (According to the docs I think TreeMap keys use equals method to match...

Here is my code. Hope someone can give it a quick browse and let me know why it doesn't work... if you uncomment the last return statement and get rid of all the map stuff you'll see my recursive only solution and that WORKS.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;


public class Coins3 {

public static class Pair implements Comparable<Pair> {
    Integer i1;
    Integer i2;

    Pair(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
        this.i1 = i1;
        this.i2 = i2;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Pair arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(this.equals(arg0)) return 0;
        return this.i1 - arg0.i1;
    }
    public boolean equals(Pair arg0) {
        if(this.i1.equals(arg0.i1) && this.i2.equals(arg0.i2)) return true;
        return false;
    }
}

static int[] coins = {1, 2, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100, 200};
static Map<Pair,Integer> memo = new TreeMap<Pair,Integer>();

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.println(nWays(coins.length,200));

}

public static int nWays(int index, int target) {

    if(target == 0) return 1;
    if(target < 0) return 0;
    if(index <= 0 && target > 0) return 0;
    // use the coin or not
    int n1, n2;
    Pair p1 = new Pair(index, target-coins[index-1]);
    Pair p2 = new Pair(index-1, target); 

    if(memo.containsKey(p1)) {
        n1 = memo.get(p1);
    } else { 
        n1 = nWays(index,target-coins[index-1]);
        memo.put(p1, n1);
    }

    if(memo.containsKey(p2)) {
        n2 = memo.get(p2);
    } else { 
        n2 = nWays(index-1,target);
        memo.put(p2, n2);
    }
    return n1 + n2;

    //return nWays(index-1,target) + nWays(index,target-coins[index-1]);


}
```

}

Comment: Your `compareTo` has no mention of i2.  This means that your equals and compareTo are inconsistent.  If a TreeMap internally uses `equals` and gets false, and then uses `compareTo` and gets 0... I'm not sure what will happen.

Comment: You need to know - stackoverflow.com/questions/17027777/relationship-between-hashcode-and-equals-method-in-java. But I also think that this is not the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

youve overridden `equals()` without overriding `hashcode()`, and used the class (class Pair) as a key in a map/set (your `memo` field).

classical beginner mistake - [read this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jtp05273/) for why you should always override `equals()` and `hashcode()` together.

**the short version**: map always uses hashcode to "narrow down" the search key you provide, and only then uses equals() to match your key against the keys it finds "in the area". since you didnt override hashcode() your calls `memo.containsKey(p1)` and `memo.containsKey(p2)` might fail to locate the keys even if equals keys to p1/p2 exist